# Why does Angular calculates view dimensions different from jQuery

Tags: jquery, angular

i've noticed that Angular calculates view dimensions differently on refresh than the jQuery does. Take a look at this:

```
@ViewChild("wrapper") wrapper: ElementRef;
//onInit
console.log("width: " +(this.wrapper.nativeElement.width()));
```

On first launch: 928
On refresh: 928

if I use jQuery:

```
@ViewChild("wrapper") wrapper: ElementRef;
//onInit
console.log("width: " +$(this.wrapper.nativeElement).width());
```

On first launch: 942
On refresh: 928

Needles to say, I spent a day figuring out whats going on here.. So why does jQuery calculates dimensions of DOM different from Angular? it happens only on rare occasions, and I cannot really put my finger on it.

Comment: offsetwidth is the width including padding and border. Width is just the width

Comment: ah, sorry. I was copy pasting at different times.  its with in both cases.

Comment: That's not related to Angular. You're just using browser API directly.